# How to receive data from bluetooth device using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

i am new to VB.NET.Currently am working in ECG project.First i will explain my concept.I have to receive data from Bluetooth device (normal BP rate ,SPO2 ) ,using that pulse i need to draw ECG wave form.I don't know how to receive data from Bluetooth device (ECG machine),i paired my mobile device to ECG device.I am new to VB.net,previously i was in android.
Some one help is appreciated ..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [32feet.net](http://32feet.codeplex.com/documentation) library. It abstracts many of the bluetooth details and I believe it is rather easy to use, even for a newcomer.

Hope I helped!